# How to slice a circle equally based on array length of elements ? Using react/javascript html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, reactjs

Trying to create a Polar/Radar Chart, I want to create separate slices of the first circle based on the length of the array items. And print each item.name in each slice equally and text style in Arc. Circle width 720px and height 720px.

When I map through the array and print names, it creates a separate circle for each name because I am mapping outside the dev.

Any ideas, solutions are appreciated. Thanks

```
    const items = [{ "id": 1, "name": "javascript" }, { "id": 2, "name": "HTML" }, { "id": 1, "name": "CSS" }]
    const length = items?.length ?? 0
    const width = 720
    const slice = width / length
     
    return (
            <div>
              { items?.map(item =>
              <div className={styles.circle} style={{width: `${slice}}}>
                <p>{item.name}</p>
              </div>
               )}
            </div>
    )

    //css
    .circle {
       height: 720px;
       border: solid 1px #fafafa;
       background: #fafafa;
       border-radius: 50%;
       padding: 20px;
       position: relative;
     }
```

Comment: You are trying to draw pie chart. You can use this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#pie

Comment: Thanks, I think a custom-built pie chart is better in my case. I have other circles within the main circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw your pie chart using `react-google-charts` easily. It supports a fair amount of options to manage the chart.

```
import React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

const data = [
  ["Language", "Popularity"],
  ["Javascript", 1],
  ["HTML", 1],
  ["CSS", 1]
];

const options = {
  legend: "none",
  pieSliceText: "label",
  title: "Language Popularity",
  pieStartAngle: 180
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Chart
      chartType="PieChart"
      data={data}
      options={options}
      width={"100%"}
      height={"400px"}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit magical-liskov-bvy4i3]

Comment: Thanks Amila for sharing this solution, I want to custom build the pie chart because there are other layers within. 

Any ideas for the custom build, please. thanks